# Can `auto const*const` by typedefed into some single-word type?

Tags: c++, constants, auto

I'd like to simplify typing of `auto const*const` construct by creating a typedef something like

```
// (pseudocode)
using deepcp=auto const*const;
deepcp a=f(1),b=f(2),c=f(3);
auto lam=[](deepcp x,deepcp y,deepcp z){ return *x+*y+*z; };
```

Can I achieve something like tihs with C++? Maybe template aliases will help somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `f` is a function (and not some macro that returns different types), and `f` returns some raw pointer type, you can use decltype:

```
using ret_f_t = decltype(f(1)); 
using pointee_t = std::pointer_traits<ret_f_t>::element_type;
using deepcp std::add_const<pointee_t>::type * const;
```

Or, as a one line mumbo jumbo:

```
using deepcp = std::add_const<
  std::pointer_traits<decltype(f(1))>::element_type
>::type * const ;
```

Yay.

Note: I used `add_const` because I don't know from your example whether `f` returns a pointer or const pointer, i.e. if `pointee_t` is const or not - this way it works for both possibilities.

[[Example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e82c4ef7beb41488)

Comment: Hmm, looks nice for initialization of variables, but doesn't seem to be general enough for the other line in OP example — generic lambda.

Comment: Well yes, I guess I wasn't explicit enough in the OP. The lambda was meant to be _really_ generic. I.e. it should accept being called like e.g. `lam(getIntPtr(),getDoublePtr(),getMyCustomTypePtr())`. I guess this is asking too much though, as `auto` has completely different meaning for generic lambdas than for variables.

Comment: @Ruslan ah I see. Well, for starters you don't nee the top level const there. And the other const is not vital either - unless your problem is more complicated than the example. So just use `[](auto, auto, auto)` and dereference whatever comes. Has the benefit that it will also work if you pass smart pointers.

Comment: Yes, I do usually just use `auto`, but sometimes generic lambda can become a bit more complex, and some const-correctness would help detect silly bugs.

Comment: @Ruslan well, the answer to your original question in case of generic lambdas is simply "can't do" -  there is no replacement for `auto const*`. So to prevent the bugs I'd in fact use `auto const*`. It may be a bit more to type, but has the benefit of not obscuring the fact that we are dealing with a generic lambda. `[](deepcp x,deepcp y,deepcp z)` does definitely NOT look generic. Having said that, it might be that with concepts you get to write that generic lambda similar to `[](ConstPtr, ConstPtr, ConstPtr)`, where `ConstPtr` is a concept.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define deepcp auto const * const
```

would do your bidding

Comment: No it won't. `b` and `c` would be declared `auto const`, not `auto const*const`, wouldn't they?

Comment: Yes.  So don't do that - declare each variable separately.

Comment: I think this is as close as you can get.

Comment: Don't use macros to define types or type aliases. That's what typedef and type aliases are for, and the standard library type traits can help.

Comment: @MartinBonner Declare each variable separately is always a good idea. `auto` is not a type, it is a keyword: while you can define new types you can't define new keywords, so I also think it is as close at it can get.